# Using php to wrap first two words in a span

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to figure out how to use php to wrap the first two words of a string in a span, it's similar to this:

[Wrap first and second word in span Clases PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25303746/wrap-first-and-second-word-in-span-clases-php)

But I need two words in the one span. Eg:

**Input string:**

`Apartment 1 8 Share`

**Expected output:**

```
<span>Apartment 1</span> 8 Share
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simplest one.

[**Regex code demo**](https://regex101.com/r/cgFSlQ/1/)

**Regex:** `^([^\h]+\s[^\h]+)`

Optionally we can use `^(\s*[^\h]+\s[^\h]+)` if white space comes at very starting.`\s*` is for zero more white spaces.

> **1.** `^` start of string.
>
> **2.** `[^\h]` match except horizontal white space.
>
> **3.** `\s` This will match space.
>
> **4.** `[^\h]+` match all except horizontal white space.
>
> **5.** `()` will capture first captured group in `$1`

Optionally we can use `\s` instead of `\h`.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/800741)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$string="Apartment 1 8 Share";
echo preg_replace("/^([^\h]+\s[^\h]+)/", "<span>$1</span>", $string);
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. I'm very new to regex so I do apologise :)